# I want to get all the wallpapers who have similar name, tags to the wallpaper which is rendered

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

views.py

```
def download(request, wallpaper_name):
    wallpaper = Wallpaper.objects.get(name=wallpaper_name)
    context = {'wallpaper': wallpaper}
    return render(request, 'Wallpaper/download.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

wallpaper model

```
class Wallpaper(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    pub_date = models.DateField('date published', null=True)
    resolution = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
```

HTML

```
<ul>
   <li>{{wallpaper.name}}</li>
   {% for i in wallpaper.tags_set.all %}
     <li>{{i.tags}}</li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

urls.py

```
path('<wallpaper_name>/', views.download, name="download"),
```

Like example the wallpaper I have choosen to download has tags nature and ocean so I want all the wallpapers who have this tag

Comment: and also in html i tried to render the tags but they are not rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
<ul>
   <li>{{wallpaper.name}}</li>
   {% for i in wallpaper.tags.all %}
     <li>{{i.tags}}</li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

instead of

```
<ul>
   <li>{{wallpaper.name}}</li>
   {% for i in wallpaper.tags_set.all %}
     <li>{{i.tags}}</li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

to get wallpaper related to tags you can do something like this

```
def download(request, wallpaper_name):
    wallpaper = Wallpaper.objects.get(name=wallpaper_name)
    related_wallpaper = Wallpaper.objects.filter(tags=wallpaper.tags.all())
    context = {'wallpaper': wallpaper,'related_wallpaper':related_wallpaper}
    return render(request, 'Wallpaper/download.html', context)
```

Comment: and what about similar wallpapers

Comment: Hello @Mario_z04 check I've edited my answer

Comment: sir its showing the same error, I think the problem is in the model.py

Comment: Can you provide that error inside your question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get Wallpapers similar to the one you have on basis of tags, you should use this library [django-taggit](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

This library's API has a method [`similar_objects()`](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#TaggableManager.similar_objects).

This is how your wallpaper model would look like.

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Wallpaper(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    pub_date = models.DateField('date published', null=True)
    resolution = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

And in your views.py

```
def download(request, wallpaper_name):
    wallpaper = Wallpaper.objects.get(name=wallpaper_name)
    similar_wallpapers = wallpaper.tags.similar_objects()
    context = {'wallpaper': wallpaper, 'similar_wallpapers': similar_wallpapers}
    return render(request, 'Wallpaper/download.html', context)
```

HTML

```
<ul>
   <li>{{wallpaper.name}}</li>
   {% for wallpaper in similar_wallpapers %}
     <li>{{wallpaper.name}}</li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This will list out the names of the wallpaper that have same or similar tags.

Comment: Wallpaper.Wallpaper.tags: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Tag', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
It is showing this error

Comment: When i tried to migrate

Comment: Check the installation steps for django-taggit, add it to installed_apps in settings.py and then run python manage.py migrate. Then you'll be able to add the TaggableManager() to your models.py

Comment: it worked but after running it shows Wallpaper.models.Wallpaper.DoesNotExist: Wallpaper matching query does not exist.